# How to clear filters on a Dash table to show the full data?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I have been trying to build an interactive dash with Dash and Plotly.

I have a few dropdowns allowing the user to select the filters.  However, my graph and piechart only show the filtered data OK, but when I clear the filters with the intention to show users about the full data analysis, the graph and charts don't work and return an empty diagram.

Any suggestion on how I should build or change for the full analysis with the full set of data, with my `update_chart` function to reflect filtered/unfiltered data respectively?

I got my `data` from Firestore and you can assume that the data is with no issue (verified).

Here's my code:

#### html

```
html.Div(
            children=[
                html.Div(
                    children=[
                        html.Div(children="State", className="menu-title"),
                        dcc.Dropdown(
                            id="state-filter",
                            options=[
                                {"label": state, "value": state}
                                for state in np.sort(data.state.unique())
                            ],
                            value="CA",
                            clearable=True,
                            className="dropdown",
                        ),
                    ]
                ),
                html.Div(
                    children=[
                        html.Div(children="Category", className="menu-title"),
                        dcc.Dropdown(
                            id="category-filter",
                            options=[
                                {"label": category, "value": category}
                                for category in data.category.unique() if not pd.isnull(category)
                            ],
                            value="web",
                            clearable=True,
                            className="dropdown",
                        ),
                    ]
                ),
                html.Div(
                    children=[
                        html.Div(
                            children="Date Range", className="menu-title"
                        ),
                        dcc.DatePickerRange(
                            id="date-range",
                            min_date_allowed=data.fundedDate.min().date(),
                            max_date_allowed=data.fundedDate.max().date(),
                            start_date=data.fundedDate.min().date(),
                            end_date=data.fundedDate.max().date(),
                        ),
                    ]
                ),
            ],
            className="menu",
        ),
        html.Div(
            children=[
                html.Div(
                    children=dcc.Graph(
                        id="funding-chart",
                        config={"displayModeBar": False},
                    ),
                    className="card",
                ),
                html.Div(
                    children=dcc.Graph(
                        id="category-chart",
                        figure={}, 
                        className='six columns',
                    ),
                ),
            ],
            className="wrapper",
        ),
```

#### data

```
@dash_app.callback(
[Output("funding-chart", "figure"), Output("category-chart", "figure")],
[
    Input("state-filter", "value"),
    Input("category-filter", "value"),
    Input("date-range", "start_date"),
    Input("date-range", "end_date"),
],
)
def update_charts(state, category, start_date, end_date):
    mask = (
        (data.state == state)
        & (data.category == category)
        & (data.fundedDate >= start_date)
        & (data.fundedDate <= end_date)
    )
    filtered_data = data.loc[mask, :]
    funding_chart_figure = {
        "data": [
            {
                "x": filtered_data["fundedDate"],
                "y": filtered_data["raisedAmt"],
                "type": "lines",
                "hovertemplate": "$%{y:.2f}<extra></extra>",
            },
        ],
        "layout": {
            "title": {
                "text": "Raised fundings by date",
                "x": 0.05,
                "xanchor": "left",
            },
            "xaxis": {"fixedrange": True},
            "yaxis": {"tickprefix": "$", "fixedrange": True},
            "colorway": ["#17B897"],
        },
    }

    category_chart_figure = px.pie(data_frame=filtered_data, values='raisedAmt',
names='category', title='Raised funding by category')
    return funding_chart_figure, category_chart_figure
```

#### With filtered data

[image]
[image]

When I want to clear the filters and just get the overview of the analysis, the `filtereddata` set is causing me to not able to get back the full data.

[image]
[image]

Any good ideas to adjust my `update_chart` function to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the issue is that "category" is empty, which causes the filter to break.

How about catching this case in an if statement at the beginning of update_charts?

```py
#[...]
def update_charts(state, category, start_date, end_date):
    category_filter = True  #get all categories if category is empty
    if category:
        category_filter = (data.category == category)
    mask = (
        (data.state == state)
        & category_filter
        & (data.fundedDate >= start_date)
        & (data.fundedDate <= end_date)
    )
    #[...]
```

Comment: it shouldn't be `category_filter` within the `mask` right? if i understand correctly the `category_filter` var is True or false

Comment: it should be in the mask: category_filter is either True (if category is empty) or a logical filter (data.category == category) for the dataframe. In both cases, it can be used in the mask, either filtering nothing (True) or filtering for the desired entries (logical filter).